# Is there a way to "limit" the result with ELOQUENT ORM of Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, sql-limit

Is there a way to "limit" the result with ELOQUENT ORM of Laravel?

```
 SELECT * FROM  `games` LIMIT 30 , 30
```

And with Eloquent ?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Create a Game model which extends Eloquent and use this:

```
Game::take(30)->skip(30)->get();
```

`take()` here will get 30 records and `skip()` here will offset to 30 records.

---

In recent Laravel versions you can also use:

```
Game::limit(30)->offset(30)->get();
```

Comment: may i ask you to take a look at a Laravel ORM related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956706/laravel-randomly-select-n-number-of-rows-containing-same-value-in-certain-colu ?

Answer (score 20):

**We can use LIMIT like bellow:**

```
Model::take(20)->get();
```

Comment: Looks like you're using take and not limit

Comment: In this case, `take` is just an alias to `limit`. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1896.

Answer (score 19):

If you're looking to paginate results, use the integrated [paginator](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination), it works great!

```
$games = Game::paginate(30);
// $games->results = the 30 you asked for
// $games->links() = the links to next, previous, etc pages
```

Comment: This is seriously amazing! Using bootstrap, literally all the code you need is $games = Game::paginate(30) in your controller and {{ $games->links() }} in your view... it takes care of everything. Loving Laravel!

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can use it following ways

To get only first

```
 $cat_details = DB::table('an_category')->where('slug', 'people')->first();
```

To get by limit and offset

```
$top_articles = DB::table('an_pages')->where('status',1)->limit(30)->offset(0)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
$remaining_articles = DB::table('an_pages')->where('status',1)->limit(30)->offset(30)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```