# laravel4 pulling latest data from database

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I have a User table and i successfully pulling data from database in to my view by the following controller

```
public function indexBloodDonation()
{

            $result = User::where('blood_group','O-')->get();
            return View::make('bloodDonation.donors')->with('result',$result);
}
```

but its in fact fetching all user whom blood group is O- ,but i want to pull **latest** 4 or 5 or 10 user,not all user from database.
What should be the laravel4 eloquent query to get **latest** data from database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to "limit" the result with ELOQUENT ORM of Laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229303/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-result-with-eloquent-orm-of-laravel) (combined with an `orderBy` call)

Answer (score 1):

Would this be what you are looking for?

```
public function indexBloodDonation()
{
     $result = User::where('blood_group','O-')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->get();
     return View::make('bloodDonation.donors')->with('result',$result);
}
```

Comment: yeah i am exactly looking for this type of eloquent ORM,i will test it very soon and if it works,then i will give you the feedback.Thanks for the answer.