# How do I grab only first 4 results from a DB query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel project I am preforming a database query where I search through my media table and grab all results that belong to a user_id. The results are ordered by most votes in descending order. However, this returns all the users images. I only want to grab the first 4 results, not all. How can this be done?

My media table looks like this.

```
| id | user_id | url | votes |
```

My controller looks like this

```
public function getUserImagesByVote($user_id)
{

    return Media::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('votes', 'DESC')->get();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to "limit" the result with ELOQUENT ORM of Laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229303/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-result-with-eloquent-orm-of-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use take() for it. I believe "Media::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('votes', 'DESC')->take(4)->get();" will help. You have take() and skip() provided by lavarvel. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries), you can use `take()` to limit the result and `skip()` to offset

> Offset & Limit
>
> $users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();

in your case use this query

```
Media::where('user_id', $user_id)->take(4)->orderBy('votes', 'DESC')->get()
```