# Select2 v4 how to paginate results using AJAX

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to paginate results (every 25 rows) using Select2 4.0, but I don't know how to achieve it. Does somebody know how to do it?

If the user reach the end of the 25 rows and if there is more rows I would like to load it and show it.

Here is my HTML template

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::select('breed_id', $breeds, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' =>'breed_id'] ) !!}
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript for Select2.

```
$("#breed_id").select2({
    placeholder: 'Breed...',
    width: '350px',
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                term: params.term
            }
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

And this is the code I have for my controller

```
if ($request->ajax())
{
    $breeds = Breed::where('name', 'LIKE',  '%' . Input::get("term"). '%')->orderBy('name')->take(25)->get(['id',DB::raw('name as text')]);

    return response()->json($breeds);
}
```

Also when I tried to put `params.page` it says "undefined".

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Select2 supports pagination when using remote data through the `pagination` key that comes out of `processResults`.

For infinite scrolling, the `pagination` object is expected to have a `more` property which is a boolean (`true` or `false`). This will tell Select2 whether it should load more results when reaching the bottom, or if it has reached the end of the results.

```
{
  results: [array, of, results],
  pagination: {
    more: true
  }
}
```

In your case, you have the ability to shape your results. So you can actually change your JSON response to match the expected format, which means you won't even need to use `processResults`.

Select2 can pass in the page number as `page` if you modify the `ajax.data` function to return it.

```
data: function(params) {
    return {
        term: params.term || "",
        page: params.page || 1
    }
},
```

And then you will be able to get the page using `Input::get('page')`. And you can calculate the total number of results to skip using `(page - 1) * resultCount`, where `resultCount` is `25` in your case. This will allow you to modify your query to combine `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to get just the results you need.

```
$page = Input::get('page');
$resultCount = 25;

$offset = ($page - 1) * $resultCount;
```

And you can use the following query to generate a `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` query (based on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15229303/359284).

```
$breeds = Breed::where('name', 'LIKE',  '%' . Input::get("term"). '%')->orderBy('name')->skip($offset)->take($resultCount)->get(['id',DB::raw('name as text')]);
```

So now `$breeds` will contain only the requested results. The only thing left to do is to shape the response to match how Select2 is expecting it. You can determine if there are more pages by checking the total number of results and seeing if you've run over the limit.

```
$count = Breed::count();
$endCount = $offset + $resultCount;
$morePages = $endCount > $count;
```

So now `$morePages` should be a boolean, which is exactly what Select2 is looking for in `pagination.more`. Now you just need to shape the response to match the format I mentioned earlier.

```
$results = array(
  "results" => $breeds,
  "pagination" => array(
    "more" => $morePages
  )
);
```

And then rendering that

```
return response()->json($results);
```

---

Putting everything together, you get this for JavaScript

```
$("#breed_id").select2({
    placeholder: 'Breed...',
    width: '350px',
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                term: params.term || '',
                page: params.page || 1
            }
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

And the following for your controller

```
if ($request->ajax())
{
    $page = Input::get('page');
    $resultCount = 25;

    $offset = ($page - 1) * $resultCount;

    $breeds = Breed::where('name', 'LIKE',  '%' . Input::get("term"). '%')->orderBy('name')->skip($offset)->take($resultCount)->get(['id',DB::raw('name as text')]);

    $count = Breed::count();
    $endCount = $offset + $resultCount;
    $morePages = $endCount > $count;

    $results = array(
      "results" => $breeds,
      "pagination" => array(
        "more" => $morePages
      )
    );

    return response()->json($results);
}
```

Comment: Wooow you really rock!! I only had to change 2 things... $morePages = $count > $endCount; and also the count has to be according to the input $count = Count(Breed::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . Input::get("term"). '%')->orderBy('name')->get(['id',DB::raw('name as text')])); 
Thanks you so much!