# Select2 Loading remote data but params.page undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

Below is my code copied from https://select2.github.io/examples.html to load remote data via Select2 in my Asp.net MVC 4 project, which displayed in a Bootstap Modal dialog, however, it always shows "params.page" is undefined, it do worked if I put a "page:1" there. What's the problem?

```
$("#ReportToEmployeeName").select2({
        placeholder: "Select Report To",
        ajax: {
            url: 'myurl ',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                console.log(params);
                return {
                    term: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page //Undefined error here
                    //page: 1 // do worked, but then pagination will not work
                };
            },
            processResults: function(data, params) {
                params.page = params.page || 1;

                return {
                    results: data.Results,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * pageSize) < data.Total
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        //escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        allowClear: true,
        //templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        //templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    });
```

Comment: What does the JSON response from the server look like?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533757/select2-v4-how-to-paginate-results-using-ajax

Comment: JSON response is like this: Object {Total: 143, Results: Array[10]}, and item in the Result array is like 
Object
id:"1001"
text:"Adam (30015)"
...

Comment: @Dario  it worked as expected after changed to "params.page || 1", thanks very much,