Jquery multiselect not working when very large number of options
I have to load total 50 000 record into select2 but its take too much time to load and also browser hang up. How to solve this issue? or any alternate solution?
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://homesweb.staah.net/common/groups/css/jquery.multiselect.css"/>
<link href="https://homesweb.staah.net/common/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://homesweb.staah.net/common/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://homesweb.staah.net/common/js/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>

<select name="rateplan[]" id="rateplan" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
</select>
<script>
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
        var data = '{"ChannelRate":{"1846525":{"id":"1846525","channelId":"131","ratePlanName":"1 Bedroom","channelsName":"tbo"},"1645656":{"id":"1645656","channelId":"53","ratePlanName":"2 Bedroom","channelsName":"Agodaycs"},"1646346":{"id":"1646346","channelId":"53","ratePlanName":"3 Bedroom","channelsName":"Agodaycs"},"1423011":{"id":"1423011","channelId":"248","ratePlanName":"4 Bedroom","channelsName":"airasia"},"1423305":{"id":"1423305","channelId":"248","ratePlanName":"5 Bedroom","channelsName":"airasia"},"1778094":{"id":"1778094","channelId":"108","ratePlanName":"6 Bedroom","channelsName":"DOTW"}}}';
        inputdata = JSON.parse(data);

        var rateplanhtml = '';
            if(typeof inputdata.ChannelRate != 'undefined' && inputdata.ChannelRate != 'null' && inputdata.ChannelRate != null) {                
            $.each(inputdata.ChannelRate, function (package, pdata) {
                rateplanhtml += '<option value="'+ pdata.id +'" class="'+ pdata.channelId +'">'+ pdata.ratePlanName + '-' + pdata.channelsName+ '</option>';
            });
            }            
        $('#rateplan').html(rateplanhtml);
        $('#rateplan').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            selectAll: true,
            search: true,
        });
    });
</script>

How to fill large number of options in multi select?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533757/select2-v4-how-to-paginate-results-using-ajax

Use server-side filtering / paging.   50,000 is too many for a user to handle anyway
