# Laravel Eloquent Query - limit on a count()

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to know if a table has more than 50 rows fitting some criteria. So, the raw query should look like this:

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (SELECT id FROM table WHERE {conditions} LIMIT 50)`

but I'm having trouble doing this through eloquent. This is what I've tried so far....

`card::where( ... )->limit(50)->count("id");`

... but this doesn't work. It doesn't make the subquery for the limit, so the limit becomes useless.

Without running a subquery that is limited, the query takes up to 10 times longer..... I'm afraid it won't be as scalable as I need.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229303/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-result-with-eloquent-orm-of-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did eventually come up with a solution to this, I just didn't post it (until now). You can just grab the ID of the 50th record to see if it exists:

```
$atLeastFifty = Card::offset(50)->value("id");

if(!empty($atLeastFifty)){
    // there are at least 50 records
}else{
    // there are less than 50 records
}
```

This is **way faster** than a `count()` when there are tons of records in the table.

Comment: Nice trick, should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: Good point, since the other answer doesn't really answer the question. I've made this the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to count number of columns, use `count()` without arguments:

```
$numberOfRows = Card::where(....)->take(50)->count();
```

Comment: unfortunately it seems that `take(50)` has the *same effect* as `limit(50)` when coupled with `count()`. The query as revealed by the logs actually doesn't change at all :P (the query is still `select count(*) as aggregate from table where ... limit 50` instead of using a subquery)

Comment: @That's how Eloquent and Query Builder do it. You need to use raw queries if this is not suitable for you.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is not quite suitable for this question. But using this method, you can count the number of records up to a certain point or, more precisely, a limit.

This will count the exact number of records up to 1000

```
$query = Model::query(); // for example some query of some model
$subQuery = $query->select('id')->limit(1000);  // make simple id selection with limit 

$count = DB::table(DB::raw("({subQuery->toSql()}) as sub"))
        ->mergeBindings($query)
        ->count(); 
// get count by reconstructing query to sub query
```