# Laravel - randomly select n number of rows containing same value in certain column after applying 'order by'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by, sql-limit

In my Laravel project, in the database table `ads`, I have  the following structure :

```
id | col1 | col2
```

col2 has values like `topad`, `bump`,`urgent` along with empty value. I want to take all the rows from the `ads` table and sort them alphabetically based on `col2` in descending order.

So I used:

```
Ads::orderBy('col2','DESC')->get()
```

Now I have 2 conditions to be applied on the query.

**1st condition :**  Suppose there are 4 rows with `topad` in `col2`, 5 rows with `urgent` in `col2`, 6 rows with `bump` in `col2` and 7 rows  each with an empty value in `col2` . So  rows with `urgent` in `col2` will appear 1st, with `topad` in `col2` will appear 2nd and with `bump` in `col2` will appear 3rd and with empty values in `col2` will appear 4th.  Now I need to randomize the rows' order within each set. For example , rows with `topad` in `col2` may have the `ids` 1,2,3,4. I want to randomize these rows (which may result into for example 4,2,1,3). But they will appear before rows containing `topad` in `col2`. Same is true for `topad` and `bump` row sets and rows containing any empty  value in `col2`.

So the query becomes :

```
Ads::orderBy('col2','DESC')->inRandomOrder()->get();
```

**2nd condition :** Suppose rows are ordered by `col2` values. But from each set of rows containing same value in `col2`, I need `n` number of rows from those that have non-empty value in `col2` i.e. **randomly** I need  `n` rows from `urgent`ed rows, `n` from `topad`ed rows, `n` from `bump`ed rows  and **all** from `empty`ed rows.

How to write the query then ?

Comment: Have you tried `inRandomOrder()` before `orderBy()`?

Comment: @Tpojka, how will that pick `n` rows ?

Comment: It was just thinking out loud. 
Or maybe `Ads::orderBy('col2','DESC')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();` 
Like making several order by clause. If you sort one column (i.e. id) col2 will seem as random. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006309/how-to-use-order-by-for-multiple-columns-in-laravel-4#answer-17006377).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with subqueries, but in my experience they take more time to execute then a few smaller ones (if they are indexed correctly). Also, you have more control over the limits and debugging issues.

```
$top_ads = Ads::whereCol2('topad')->inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get();
$urgent_ads = Ads::whereCol2('urgent')->inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
$bump_ads = Ads::whereCol2('bump')->inRandomOrder()->limit(2)->get();
```

This will create your queries and after that you can do whatever you want with their collections. Combine them, reorder them, etc.

Comment: what does `whereCol2` mean ? Is it any special syntax of Laravel ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed yes, it's short for `::where('col2', $var)` or `::where('col2', '=', $var)` and is part of Laravel

Comment: where is it documented in Laravel doc ?

Comment: They were removed from the docs in 5.1 for some reason, but they are still valid. [5.0 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects) and scroll down to Dynamic Where Clauses.