# How to get Next record or previous record Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, button, pagination

I want to get the next participant if i press next button sort by category and sort by gymnast tag

here my code to get first users

```
$selectparticipant = Magmodel::where('IDEVENT', '=', $id)
              ->where('SESSION', '=', $selectsession)
              ->where('GROUP', '=', $selectgroup)
              ->orderBy('Category', 'ASC')
              ->orderBy('TAG', 'ASC')->first();
```

i want it get second record if i press next

here my code to get next participant

```
$selectparticipant = Magmodel::where('IDEVENT', '=', $ied)
              ->where('SESSION', '=', $selectsession)
              ->where('GROUP', '=', $selectgroup)
              ->where('gymnastmag.TAG', '>', $ps->TAG)
              ->orderBy('Category', 'ASC')
              ->orderBy('TAG', 'ASC')->first();
```

but it will not show the next record if it has different Category but smaller tag

here my database

[image]

i want it show Bon first when i press next show Johny,
when press next again show Ryan,
when press next again Show Lucas,
when press next again show Abraham,
when press next again show Lucky,
when press next again show Bernard,

can someone please help me with next and prev function

Comment: You will need to use `limit` & `offset` for next/previous records. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229303/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-result-with-eloquent-orm-of-laravel for more details

Comment: How many total records are there or could become?

Comment: For total record it can goes up to 50 records

Comment: @MichaelRitung Then fetch all records, throw them to the browser, and do the prev and next actions in the frontend itself.